# Docker Compose: Nginx and PHP-FPM not working

Tags: php, nginx, docker-compose

I'm testing docker compose with Nginx and php-fpm, but this fail.
My docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles/nginx/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    links:
      - php

  php:
    container_name: php-fpm
    image: php:7-fpm
    volumes:
      - ./project/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

This is my dockerfile Nginx:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY config/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

And dafault.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name localhost;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

when I try localhost: 8000 returns the following message:

"File not found."

but, the index.php is in the project/ path.

that I am wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to use volumes_from in your nginx container in the compose file, now you have in nginx:

```
volumes:
  - ./project/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
```

And in php

```
volumes:
  - ./project/:/var/www/html/
```

They should be the same.

Comment: the problem was both must point to the same volume. for example: /var/www/html